# How to use client only plugins for Inertia SSR + Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I'm Using Laravel10 (jetstream) + Vue3 + InertiaJS. I would like to Enable SSR for the project but I have problems with plugin [Vue apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/).
It doesn't work.

Also i have had the same problem with [@fawmi/vue-google-maps](https://github.com/fawmi/vue-google-maps)

Google didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only can say about vue-google-map
try this lib [vue3-google-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-google-map)

if  you use vite you need to add to your vite config this

```
ssr: {
  noExternal: [...yours lib,"vue3-google-map",...yours lib],
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Same problem on the same stack with PrimeVue plugin. Following the thread.

My error :

directory import '/path_to_project/node_modules/primevue/config' is not supported resolving es modules imported from /path_to_project/bootstrap/ssr/ssr.mjs

Comment: Thx for reaching out but unfortunately It does not seems an answer for the posted question, but a similar issue. You can save the question for future reference or ask another question, but please do not post answers with not relevant information.